# StreamWriter and StreamReader and array problems

Tags: c#, arrays

```
I have this very long code, which is works more or less.
```

The problem is it's not writing into text file, and when I open `FrmDc` `FrmMarvel` also opens. Some reason while I'm closing `FrmDc` `Index was outside the bounds of the arrays` message is shown. What could be wrong? 
The reading is works more or less also, because when I write some information to a textbox, and the source file contains details, it duplicates the existing texts.

I think I can remove some part of the code, but I'm not sure which.

```
namespace Kepregenybolt
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            List<CsMarvel> kLista = new List<CsMarvel>();
            StreamWriter sW;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                cbKiado.Items.Add("Marvel");
                cbKiado.Items.Add("DC");
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sR = new StreamReader("kepregenyek.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
                    while (!sR.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string sor = sR.ReadLine();
                        string[] s = sor.Split(';');
                        if (s.Length == 5)
                        {
                            CsMarvel h = new CsMarvel(s[0],
                                s[1],
                                s[2],
                                Convert.ToInt32(s[3]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(s[4]));
                            kLista.Add(h);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CsDc h = new CsDc(s[0],
                               s[1],
                               s[2],
                               Convert.ToInt32(s[3]),
                               Convert.ToInt32(s[4]),
                               s[5]);
                            kLista.Add(h);
                        }
                    }
                    sR.Close();
                    foreach (CsMarvel item in kLista)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(item.listába());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void cbKiado_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FrmMarvel a = new FrmMarvel(kLista);

                if (cbKiado.Text.Equals("Marvel")) ;



                a.ShowDialog();
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sR = new StreamReader("kepregenyek.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
                    while (!sR.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string sor = sR.ReadLine();
                        string[] s = sor.Split(';');
                        CsMarvel l = new CsMarvel(s[0], s[1], s[2], Convert.ToInt32(s[3]), Convert.ToInt32(s[4]));
                        kLista.Add(l);
                    }

                    sR.Close();
                    foreach (CsMarvel item in kLista)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(item.listába());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                } 

                if (cbKiado.Text.Equals("DC"));
                {
                    FrmDc b = new FrmDc(kLista);
                    b.ShowDialog();
                    try
                    {
                        StreamReader sR = new StreamReader("kepregenyek.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
                        while (!sR.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            string sor = sR.ReadLine();
                            string[] s = sor.Split(';');
                            CsDc l = new CsDc(s[0], s[1], s[2], Convert.ToInt32(s[3]), Convert.ToInt32(s[4]), s[5]);
                            kLista.Add(l);
                        }

                        sR.Close();
                        foreach (CsDc item in kLista)
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(item.listába());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                    }
                }
            }


            private void FrmMarvel_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
            {

                sW = new StreamWriter("kepregenyek.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8);
                foreach (CsMarvel item in kLista)
                {
                    sW.WriteLine(item.fájlba());
                }
                sW.Close();
            }

            private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The CsMarvel is the following:

```
    public class CsMarvel
        {
            string cim;
            string iro;
            string rajzolo;
            int megjelenes;
            int ar;




            public CsMarvel(string cim, string iro, string rajzolo, int megjelenes, int ar)
            {
                this.cim = cim;
                this.iro = iro;
                this.rajzolo = rajzolo;
                this.megjelenes = megjelenes;
                this.ar = ar;

            }
            public virtual string fájlba()
            {
                return this.cim + ";" + this.iro + ";" + this.rajzolo + ";" + this.megjelenes + ";" + this.ar;
            }
            public virtual string listába()
            {
                return this.cim + ":" + this.iro + " " + this.rajzolo + " kiadó Kiadva:" + this.megjelenes + " " + this.ar + " Ft";
            }
            public string Cim
            {
                get
                {
                    return cim;

                }
                set
                {
                    cim = value;
                }
            }
            public string Iro
            {
                get
                {
                    return iro;

                }
                set
                {
                    iro = value;
                }
            }
            public string Rajzolo
            {
                get
                {
                    return rajzolo;

                }
                set
                {
                    rajzolo = value;
                }
            }
            public int Megjelenes
            {
                get
                {
                    return megjelenes;

                }
                set
                {
                    megjelenes = value;
                }
            }
            public int Ar
            {
                get
                {
                    return ar;

                }
                set
                {
                    ar = value;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

And the CsDc has one extra array.

Comment: SO is not for code review. consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How `item.fájlba()` is defined? Could you paste code for this method?

Comment: Yes, in CsMarvel, like this: 
`public virtual string fájlba()
        {
            return this.cim + ";" + this.iro + ";" + this.rajzolo + ";" + this.megjelenes + ";" + this.ar;
        }`

Comment: @Gary so none of those parameters are arrays or something?

Comment: these are all parameters.strings and ints

Comment: @Gary Moreover, why do you have this code `if (cbKiado.Text.Equals("DC"));`? It will make so that everything underneath will run any way.

Comment: I would say you are doing a loooot of reading and a few times. That is probably not needed. But I can't say what exactly, because I don't know your needs.

Comment: It's for a ComboBox, which leads to an other form. I'm real beginner, so it seem the only way to make a ComboBox situation.

Comment: You have too many mistakes. You have to [separate your code into simple steps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [fix each step one by one](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Do not try to solve two problems at the same time

Comment: A couple of tips... If someone indicates that more information is required (like the definition of `fájlba`) it's worth putting that in the question so that everyone can see it, and it formats correctly. Secondly: StreamReader and StreamWriter are both IDisposable so variables of those types are best declared as local variables in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need the Close, as the implicit Dispose will call Close as it exits the block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got duplicates because of `if...` in `cbKiado_SelectedIndexChanged()`

```
if (cbKiado.Text.Equals("DC"));
{
...
}
```

You need to remove `;` if you would like to run `{...}` code block only if text is `DC`. You have now situation when you run empty block in true case and run `{...}` always. It will make reading of file twice, I suppose.

Comment: That was really helpful, now those codes run separately. The `Index was outside the bounds of the arrays` problem is still on, and the StreamWriter just write to ListBox, not to the file.

Comment: @Gary In DC case you are reading line and trying to take s[5] value. Suppose something could be wrong there.

Comment: DC has more parameter, That's why I used 5 not 4.

Comment: @Gary So you writing in two different ways? Because you showed only one which is not dependent on DC or not.

Comment: Maybe now can be seen. Updated question.